# RegEx: How to split url into two part with iis rewrite rule

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

so these is my url which i need to split into two part.

1) http://localhost:8800/

2) http://localhost:8800/About.aspx

3) http://localhost:8800/product.aspx?id=1&vref=201

4) http://localhost:8800/Contact.aspx

5) http://localhost:8800/Contact/india or http://localhost:8800/Contact/usa

see the above url and i want to split those url into two part using a single regex

1) first url has only one part 
2) second url has two part like
   http://localhost:8800 and About.aspx

3) 3rd url has two part like
   http://localhost:8800 and product.aspx?id=1&vref=201

4) 4th url has two part like
   http://localhost:8800 and Contact.aspx

5) 4th url has two part like
   http://localhost:8800 and Contact/india or http://localhost:8800/Contact/usa

now tell me what regex i should apply in iis url rewrite rule which will split the above url in two part the way i describe here. please help me with exact regex which would work in iis rewrite rule pattern test.

Comment: will it always start with `http://localhost:8800`?

Comment: when testing from local iis then url start with http://localhost:8800 but the moment i will host the site then url may start like `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: What about the http part? is it always there?

Comment: Your host is inside `{HTTP_HOST}`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables.

Comment: @Sweeper yes http or https will be always there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/(.*)
```

Group 1 is the first part. Group 2 is the second part.

It works by first finding `http://` or `https://` followed by a bunch of non-forward-slashes. It puts all that into group 1. Then, it looks for a forward slash. and finally, puts the rest of the string into group 2.

- `()` is capturing group. The first pair of `()` is group 1, the second pair is group 2, and so on.
- `s?` means that the `s` is optional
- `\/` matches `/` literally. You can just write `/` in some flavours
- `[^]` is a reverse character class. It will match anything except the characters inside it.
- `.` matches everything except line terminators.
- `*` means 0 or more times.

try it here: https://regex101.com/r/S9yg0C/2

Comment: great answer. thanks a lot for saving my day. i am weak in regex. i need a guide line how could i learn and become string in regex. please advise me. thanks

Comment: @Thomas practice makes perfect.

Comment: if possible can you please explain your all regex character meaning.

Comment: @Thomas Go to the link. The regex is explained on the top right.

Comment: @Thomas no I mean the link in the answer

Comment: i request suppose my url is http://localhost:8800/gb/Contact.aspx now tell what regex i should use to get second part of from after country code means Contact.aspx

Comment: @Thomas you should ask a new question, but try something yourself first. This is out of the scope of this question.